# Typesafe Activator Throws A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while trying to run the UI

Tags: typesafe-activator

I am trying to run the Typesafe activator's UI. When I run it, it acts like it is downloading everything successfully, but the throws a java.lang.IlleagalArgumentException. I have tried multiple times to run it, but I keep getting this error:

```
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.10)...
   ... our current version 1.2.10 looks like the latest.
Found previous process id: 2816
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file://C:/Users/Elijah/.activator/repository
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(UIMain.scala:103)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(UIMain.scala:100)
        at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$runWith$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:
136)
        at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$runWith$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:
135)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimize
d.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.collect(TraversableLike.scala:
282)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.collect(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:100)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:87)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an autho
rity component
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can't think of what more to do. Is this a problem that can be fixed?? I have tried google, but have found nothing of use.

Comment: I have the same thing with Play Framework 2.3.5. I downloaded version 2.3.4 from [the Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/download#older-versions) website and  that does not have this problem.

Comment: I also had to delete the directory `C:\Users\<myusername>\.activator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the same error by moving the location of the activator directory from "My Documents" to "c:\tmp".

This link has details that the path must not contain a space: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file `C:/Users/Elijah/.activator/repository` or `.sbt/repository` contains a `file://` reference with two forward slashes. Add a third slash to the file references and try again. I had a similar problem with SBT, and this fixed it. Beware that activator tends to overwrite this.

See [this post](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1037) for some more info

Comment: Don't put a third slash, put a total of four slashes  ( file://// ) when using Windows local path variables. When using UNC paths just two slashes will work.